# Unity android build crash : android.view.ViewGroup.offsetRectBetweenParentAndChild

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, crash

**Got This crash on unity 3d android build, unable to understand why this crash occurs , **

Caused by

- at android.view.ViewGroup.offsetRectBetweenParentAndChild
  (ViewGroup.java:6415) at
  android.view.ViewGroup.offsetDescendantRectToMyCoords
  (ViewGroup.java:6341) at
  android.view.ViewRootImpl.scrollToRectOrFocus
  (ViewRootImpl.java:4699) at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw
  (ViewRootImpl.java:4230) at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw
  (ViewRootImpl.java:4074) at
  android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:3332)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:2134) at
  android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run
  (ViewRootImpl.java:8612) at
  android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run
  (Choreographer.java:1035) at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks
  (Choreographer.java:858) at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame
  (Choreographer.java:789) at
  android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run
  (Choreographer.java:1020) at android.os.Handler.handleCallback
  (Handler.java:938) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage
  (Handler.java:99) at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:236) at
  android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8051) at
  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method) at
  com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
  (RuntimeInit.java:620) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
  (ZygoteInit.java:1011)

---

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.